# Como enviar un formulario a mi REST APi en React?

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes, tengo este formulario en mi render

```
  <form className="form-horizontal" role="form">

                   <p><input type="text" className="form-control" 
                    id="name" placeholder="Name" required/></p>
                    <input type="submit" value="send" />

    </form>
```

Y en mi api tengo una url por post que seria `localhost:3000/api/categories/create/:nombre` en nombre iria el nombre ingresado en el formulario. Cual es la mejor forma de hacer esto en React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que tienes dudas sobre "buenas prácticas" en React. Todas ellas se pueden despejar si:

- Lees la [documentación](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html)
- Lees artículos como [éste](https://blog.risingstack.com/react-js-best-practices-for-2016/)
- Buscas material útil como [éste](https://github.com/planningcenter/react-patterns)

De preferencia tomarle mayor atención a artículos de personalidades que manejan bien el tema.

---

Hacer un submit en React es igual que en VanillaJS, no hay mayor misterio. Si bien en React los eventos no son nativos, a nivel de funcionalidad no hay mayores diferencias.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />
  <button type="submit">Enviar nombre</button>
</form>

...
onInputChange (e) {
  this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
}

onSubmit (e) {
  fetch (`localhost:3000/api/categories/create/${this.state.name}`, {
    method: 'POST'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.success) { // exito
      alert('Categoría creada');
    }
  });
}
```

Cuando tratamos con formularios por lo general tendemos a hablar de componentes *controlados* y *no controlados*. Un componente *no controlado* es un elemento autocontrolado sin depender ni estar sincronizado con un contexto. Puedes pensar en un `<input type="text" value="Hola"/>` como un componente no controlado.

Por otro lado, un componente controlado es aquel que es controlado por un contexto, manteniéndose siempre sincronizado con éste, por ejemplo: `<input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />`. En [éste enlace](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/) puedes ver un post que habla de ésto.

Hacer un componente controlado tiene muchas ventajas en comparación de un no controlado; ergo, no es un "debe ser", si no un "podría ser". Algunas ventajas para formularios son:

- validación instantánea
- cambio de estado automáticamente (por ejemplo, en el caso de un botón)
- forzar un formato de entrada (e incluso cambiarlo en tiempo real)

Comment: Perfecto, funciono y muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de darme info para aprender :)

Comment: Un gusto, Santiago.